# ¿Cómo poner dos card de forma horizontal?

Tags: html, css

los card estan de forma vertical pero Quiero ponerlos de forma horizontal estos dos , pero no lo logro.-el ejercicio es de un profesor por lo cual no lo hice yo ,  quiero complemetarlo arreglando eso gracias

Este es el Html

```
<div class="viewport">
 <div class="flip-card">
  <div class="card-front">
  <p>Código: CA-01 <br>
     Fecha Captura: 6/09/2020
  </p>
  <img class="residuo" src="img/img1.png">
  </div>
<div class="card-back">
  <p>Clasificación: Metal </p>
  <img src="img/bote2.png">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="viewport">
 <div class="flip-card">
  <div class="card-front">
  <p>Código: CA-02 <br>
     Fecha Captura: 6/09/2020
  </p>
  <img class="residuo" src="img/img1.png">
</div>
<div class="card-back">
  <p>Clasificación: otro </p>
  <img src="img/bote3.png">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

-----------este es el css(los card tienen rotacion por lo que el css es largo)-------------------intente cambiando las posiciones pero no tengo idea,gracias

```
 .flip-card {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 250px;
  height: 330px;
  }
 .flip-card .card-front,
 .flip-card .card-back {
 -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
 -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms;
 -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms;
 -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms;
 transition: transform 500ms;
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 }

 .flip-card .card-front {
 -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0);
 -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0);
 transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0);
 z-index: 900;
  }
   .flip-card .card-back {
     -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
     transform: rotateY(-180deg);
     z-index: 800;
   }
   .flip-card:hover .card-front {
     -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
     transform: rotateY(180deg);
     -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(180deg);
     -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(180deg);              
     transform: perspective(300) rotateY(180deg);
   }
   .flip-card:hover .card-back {
     z-index: 950;
     transform: rotateY(0deg);
     transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
   }

   /*** Just for show... ***/
   .flip-card {
     color: #000;
     cursor: pointer;
     float: left;
     font-weight: bold;
     margin: 10px;
     text-align: center;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     min-width: 100px;
     max-width: 400px;
   }
   .flip-card .card-front,
   .flip-card .card-back {
     border-radius: 10px;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(14, 85, 143, 0.8);
     box-sizing: border-box;
     padding: 40px 0;
   }
   .flip-card .card-front {
     box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(115, 113, 113, 0.94) inset;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     background-color: #fff;
     *zoom: 1;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FF499BEA',                      
     endColorstr='#FF207CE5');
     background-size: 100%;
   }
   .flip-card .card-back {
     box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(115, 113, 113, 0.94) inset;
     background-color: #fff;
     *zoom: 1;
     filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FF478CE0',        
    endColorstr='#FF0263DB');
     background-size: 100%;
   }

   body {

   }

   .viewport {
     margin: 10px auto 0;
     width: 500px;
   }

   .flip-card .card-front img {
     margin-top: 30px;
   }
```

> intente con posicion relativa,mirando si con los display cambia la posicion pero no..no sale erro solo que siguen saliendo como columna

Comment: intente con  posicion relativa,mirando si con los display cambia la posicion pero no..no sale erro solo que siguen saliendo como columna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alcanza con hacer lo siguiente para evitar mover el código del ejercicio de tu profesor:

- Crea un **`section`** con la clase **`.contenedor`** y dentro de este mueve todo tu HTML
- En el CSS aplica un **display** de tipo **`flex`** para lograr que los elementos se mueven sobre el eje horizontal y queden uno a lado del otro

Es decir:

```
<section class="contenedor">
    .......resto de tu HTML
</section>
```

Y en tu CSS

```
.contenedor {
    display: flex;
}
```

Ahora tu ejercicio completo:

```html
    <style>
      .contenedor {
        display: flex;
      }
    .flip-card {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1000;
      width: 250px;
      height: 330px;
      }
     .flip-card .card-front,
     .flip-card .card-back {
     -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
     -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms;
     -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms;
     -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms;
     transition: transform 500ms;
     display: block;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     }
    
     .flip-card .card-front {
     -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0);
     -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0);
     transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0);
     z-index: 900;
      }
       .flip-card .card-back {
         -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
         -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
         transform: rotateY(-180deg);
         z-index: 800;
       }
       .flip-card:hover .card-front {
         -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
         -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
         -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
         transform: rotateY(180deg);
         -moz-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(180deg);
         -webkit-transform: perspective(300) rotateY(180deg);              
         transform: perspective(300) rotateY(180deg);
       }
       .flip-card:hover .card-back {
         z-index: 950;
         transform: rotateY(0deg);
         transform: perspective(300) rotateY(0deg);
       }
    
       /*** Just for show... ***/
       .flip-card {
         color: #000;
         cursor: pointer;
         float: left;
         font-weight: bold;
         margin: 10px;
         text-align: center;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         min-width: 100px;
         max-width: 400px;
       }
       .flip-card .card-front,
       .flip-card .card-back {
         border-radius: 10px;
         box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(14, 85, 143, 0.8);
         box-sizing: border-box;
         padding: 40px 0;
       }
       .flip-card .card-front {
         box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(115, 113, 113, 0.94) inset;
         box-sizing: border-box;
         background-color: #fff;
         *zoom: 1;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FF499BEA',                      
         endColorstr='#FF207CE5');
         background-size: 100%;
       }
       .flip-card .card-back {
         box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(115, 113, 113, 0.94) inset;
         background-color: #fff;
         *zoom: 1;
         filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FF478CE0',        
        endColorstr='#FF0263DB');
         background-size: 100%;
       }
    
       body {
    
       }
    
       .viewport {
         margin: 10px auto 0;
         width: 500px;
       }
    
       .flip-card .card-front img {
         margin-top: 30px;
       }
    </style>
    <section class="contenedor">
      <div class="viewport">
     <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="card-front">
      <p>Código: CA-01 <br>
         Fecha Captura: 6/09/2020
      </p>
      <img class="residuo" src="img/img1.png">
      </div>
    <div class="card-back">
      <p>Clasificación: Metal </p>
      <img src="img/bote2.png">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="viewport">
     <div class="flip-card">
      <div class="card-front">
      <p>Código: CA-02 <br>
         Fecha Captura: 6/09/2020
      </p>
      <img class="residuo" src="img/img1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-back">
      <p>Clasificación: otro </p>
      <img src="img/bote3.png">
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

**Referencia**

- [CSS FlexBox](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Conceptos_Basicos_de_Flexbox)

Comment: Correcto si sirvio,muchas gracias